# How to add conditional tooltip in JSF

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, tooltip

Hi I need to display a tool-tip in a jsf element based on a flag value(true/false).

**Element:**

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg['dealsheet.label.nonpromoted']}" />
```

**Tooltip Text:** "*This denotes the status of the deal*"

**Condition:** `#{ds.partialLockOutFlag}`

When the value of the above flag is true, the tooltip message should be visible over the label while hovering.

Can anyone advice how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display your message when true, otherwise display empty string:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg['dealsheet.label.nonpromoted']}" title="#{ds.partialLockOutFlag} ? 'This denotes the status of the deal' : '' " />
```